# Python logging creates empty files

Tags: python, logging

I am using python's logging facility. I only want a log file created if there is something to log. In other words, no log file should be created if there was nothing to log.

As soon as

```
logging.basicConfig( filename=filename_log, level=logging.DEBUG, mode='w')
```

is ran, an empty log file is created. I try to delete it before exiting with:

```
if ( os.stat( filename_log ).st_size == 0 ): os.remove( filename_log)
```

which gives an error message:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

So I suppose something else should be done before.

So, is there any way not to have empty log files generated without writing my own logging procedure?

In short:

```
logging.basicConfig( filename=filename_log, level=logging.DEBUG, mode='w')
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

does log properly but gives an empty file if there is nothing to be logged. And

```
with open( filename_log, 'w') as logfile:
    logging.basicConfig( stream=logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

gives a: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the way Windows handles I/O. On a *nix system I would suggest that the I/O stream is not closed by the logging function that handles it.

```
logging.basicConfig( filename=filename_log, level=logging.DEBUG, mode='w')

...
logging.shutdown()
if os.stat(file_name).st_size == 0 : 
    os.remove(filename_log)
```

Comment: The "with open" gives a "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" so the log file must exist before.

Comment: Are you sure you tried  `with open` in write mode, i.e. with the `'w'` flag `with open(..., 'w')`?

Comment: and with the 'w' addition to "with open()" it does create the  file properly. But now it won't log: a call to logging.debug() now gives a "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'".

Comment: I've changed my answer to close the logging via the `logging.shutdown` function.

Comment: with logging.shutdown it now works fine. Thanks a lot! Not sure how I should mark an answer to be the correct and final one in here though.

Comment: Glad to hear. Then you might consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Use `filemode` instead of `mode`.